# How to link logged-in user with certain privileges to the database?

Tags: php, mariadb, frontend, backend

This is more of a best-practice question, as I am new in the web development field. I have an online-exam web-app which can be used by users with three different roles: student, teacher and admin. Teacher and admin can log in using a username and password. Students do not log in, they receive a code from the teacher to access the application/questions.
I'm using AngularJS, PHP and MariaDB for this app. The php-db access is done using the PDO extension.

My question: How can I connect a user with a certain role with the database?

I know how to create roles, grant permissions and link a user to a role in MariaDB. I also know that PDO needs a username and a (hashed) password to connect to the db and I've read somewhere, that it is better to always open and close the connection for each db-access instead of keeping it alive through the whole session.

What I do not know:

1. Should the web-app and db log-in data be the same? If yes, where do I get them from? Or should I always send them from frontend to backend? And what about the password since it's hashed?
2. What can I do for the student-role, since they access the db in a different manner?
3. Where should I store the username and password for the teacher role? In a different db? But which db log-in data do I use to access the (second) db?

For now I am using a single database and my log-in data (hardcoded) for every backend call. On another note: Is there a way to hide the code, something like encrypting it or something like that? Or is mod-rewriting enough?

I tried searching about these topics, but I do not get a good answer. Most Google results talk only about granting privileges. As I said in the beginning, I am new to this and I want to learn it the correct way.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, if I'm understanding you correctly, the student/teacher and admin roles are the users of your system. Yes? You PHP database access is completely separate from the system/site users.

> "How can I connect a user with a certain role with the database?"
>   "Should the web-app and db log-in data be the same? If yes, where do I
>   get them from? Or should I always send them from frontend to backend?
>   And what about the password since it's hashed?"

These users and your database user having nothing to do with each other. Your database access is what your PHP will use to access the database. 
You should only need the one username and password to connect to your database.
From there your users are managed by a table in the database. Something like

```
CREATE TABLE userdetails
(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(100),
password VARCHAR(100), -- This can be set more based on what hashing you use. I suggest BCrypt
role_id INT NOT NULL, -- Link this to a user_roles table.
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

> What can I do for the student-role, since they access the db in a
>   different manner?

Why not use the same user system as admin/teachers? Just have random codes for the username and password

> Where should I store the username and password for the teacher role?
>   In a different db? But which db log-in data do I use to access the
>   (second) db?

I would use a single user table with a role field to differentiate the types of users

> Is there a way to hide the code

What code specifically? The HTML cannot be hidden I'm afraid and your PHP should never be visible (unless the server is configured incorrectly)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! My main issue is how to grant a user (with a certain role) access to the database. So, you are saying, I should always use the same log-in data in the php code to open a connection to the database, regardless of the user who is currently logged in?

Comment: That sounds like an entirely different thing. Access to the database is a dev/admin thing, not something for front-end users. Users don't connect to the database. The app does.